# Taskdef fails with error: classname attribute of taskdef element is undefined

Tags: ant, taskdef

I have an Ant buildfile with this line in it:

```
<taskdef name="for" classname="net.sf.antcontrib.logic.For" />
```

The build fails on this line saying:

```
classname attribute of taskdef element is undefined
```

I think this means that Ant cannot find the class file.

Where is Ant looking for this file?  Where can I find it to add it to location X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:** Where is ant looking for this file?

Insert these into your `build.xml` file:

```
<echo message="ant home is: ${ant.home}"></echo>
<echo message="user home is: ${user.home}"></echo>
```

[(Source)](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)

**Q2:** Where can I find it to add it to location X.

Enter the class name into http://www.findjar.com/